# Inappropriate use of setInterval

Tags: javascript, setinterval

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

            var inter;
            var seconds = 1;

            function recharge() 
            {
                inter = window.setInterval( "printA()" , 1000 );
            }

            function printA()
            {
                document.write( "you are here: " + seconds + " seconds" );
                seconds++;
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <button onclick="recharge();"> Start </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

my problem is... `recharge()` contains a `setInterval()` that contains a function `printA()` this 
function that does is print whit a `document.write` a variable that sum one every time that `recharge` 
is called.. but just print 1 and doesnt print the next number. I tried whit a `alert` instead of `document.write`
and its work so I don't know what i am doing wrong. i am a noob. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Write `printA`, not `"printA()"`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So as I'm understanding your question and comments, you want to print something like this:

> you are here: 2 seconds
>
> you are here: 3 seconds
>
> you are here: 4 seconds

I would recommend doing something like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" language="JavaScript">

            var inter;
            var seconds = 1;

            function recharge() 
            {
                inter = window.setInterval( "printA()" , 1000 );
            }

            function printA()
            {
                document.body.innerHTML += "<div>you are here "+seconds+" seconds</div>";
                seconds++;
            }
        </script>

    </head>
    <body>
            <button onclick="recharge();"> Start </button>
    </body>
</html>
```

The += will keep appending html to the document.

Comment: I'm sorry, could you be more specific with your question so I can help you solve the problem?

Comment: im sorry conecction problems...
actually i chose your first opcion:


    you are here: 2 seconds

    you are here: 3 seconds

    you are here: 4 seconds
but it doesnt work for me...

Comment: I've updated my answer. Does that solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

When you document.write(), the whole page is re-written, meaning all your JavaScript is lost. alert() should work however - what did you try? The innerHTML method by winhowes works probably best. Also I don't see what 'recharge();' is supposed to achieve.

Comment: i am so grateful, but can you explain me what happen using the document.write please.

Comment: say you've got 'myPage.htm' loaded. when you use document.write() this page is overwritten, and you lose all JS functions, CSS styles, etc..., because the old page is gone.

Comment: thank you so much i had no idea. im just start to learning to programming can you please recomment some book  or something. thank you.